# Mesh Deform is not effecting some bones on the hand of my character. (Rigify/Lattice problem)

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I am new to blender and I created a character consisting of separate meshes (Coat, Scarf, Hand, Face etc...). In order to control my meshes under a rigified rig, I created a lattice mesh that covers all of the other meshes. Lattice mesh is attached to the rig and works perfectly. All the meshes except hands work in harmony. Here is the detailed explanation of the system.(Lattice mesh is the wireframe one and covers everything.)[image]

Lattice mesh deforms nicely with the rig, as well as all the clothing except the HAND.
The problem is, when i rotate the hand this happens.
The rig looks like this and not all the bones are green. Weight paint of the lattice is good and hand doesn't exceed the boundaries of the lattice.[image]

How can I get the hands not deforming badly when rotated? Any help would be very apperaciated. Thank you for your attention/help.

Answer (score 1):

This might be similar to what you're looking for; it uses the mesh deform modifier. I was having the same problem as you for a while.
Here's a video that helped: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYzR4jY8wi4

Here's a little in-depth tutorial:

1. Grab your body (not the mesh deform) and create a Vertex Group and weight paint just the hands and feet (and maybe the head and/or groin for some people, wherever there’s unwanted movement created by mixing both the mesh deform and the parented body - as you can see I didn’t include the eyes bc I liked how the mesh deform deformed them).
   [image: As you can see I didn’t include the eyes bc I liked how the mesh deform deformed them.]
2. Go to your modifiers and add an armature modifier and add your vertex group to the vertex group section. Do the same thing for the mesh deform, but also check the arrows button next to it (it inverses the chosen vertex group).
   [image]

Hope this helps!!!